# How to group by timestamp and other columns in Polars

Tags: aggregate, python-polars

I have a dataframe with many columns, only interested in timestamp, country, province, and population.

I would like to determine the mean population over time by province. I can calculate this using the following in Polars: `df.groupby(['timestamp','country', 'prov']).agg(pl.col('population').mean())`

However I would like to incorporate rolling timewindows. I have found the following, but I am unsure if I can incorporate both into one expression. `df.groupby_rolling('timestamp', period = '1y')`

I am looking to find the mean by year, perhaps rolling window is not the correct terminology

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reproducible example? Also, see the `by` argument for `groupby_rolling`, e.g. `df.groupby_rolling('timestamp', by=['country', 'prov'], period='1y')`

Comment: @Wayoshi it seems to be working with your suggestion. I was hoping to get a mean per 1 year timestamp, however I don't believe rolling is the way to go. I think I will need to chunk it up before aggregating - thanks for your help!

Comment: Then maybe `group_by_dynamic` is what you are looking for? `df.group_by_dynamic("timestamp", every="1y", by=["country", "prov"])`

Comment: @keraion That is exactly the function that I am looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For grouping data into interval based sizes, take a look at `group_by_dynamic`. The `every` parameter will define the interval to group the data, and `by` will add the additional grouping levels for the intervals.

The `group_by_dynamic` requires that your data is sorted on the index column (e.g. `timestamp`).

> index_column: Column used to group based on the time window. Often of type Date/Datetime. This column must be sorted in ascending order (or, if by is specified, then it must be sorted in ascending order within each group).`

```py
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [datetime(2022, n + 1, 1) for n in range(12)] * 6
        + [datetime(2023, n + 1, 1) for n in range(12)] * 6,
        "country": ["USA", "CAN", "MEX"] * 48,
        "prov": ["Florida", "Ontario", "Oaxaca", "California", "Quebec", "Jalisco"]
        * 24,
        "population": range(500, 644, 1),
    }
)

print(
    df.sort("timestamp")
    .group_by_dynamic("timestamp", every="1y", by=["country", "prov"])
    .agg(pl.col("population").mean())
)
```

Results:

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ country ┆ prov    ┆ timestamp           ┆ population │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---                 ┆ ---        │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ USA     ┆ Florida ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 533.0      │
│ USA     ┆ Florida ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 605.0      │
│ CAN     ┆ Ontario ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 534.0      │
│ CAN     ┆ Ontario ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 606.0      │
│ …       ┆ …       ┆ …                   ┆ …          │
│ CAN     ┆ Quebec  ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 537.0      │
│ CAN     ┆ Quebec  ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 609.0      │
│ MEX     ┆ Jalisco ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 538.0      │
│ MEX     ┆ Jalisco ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 610.0      │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```